ModuleNotFoundError from python notebook
My folder structure looks like this:
\__app
   \____init__.py
   \__models
      \____init__.py
      \__claims
         \____init__.py
         \__common.py
\__notebooks
   \__main.ipynb

From main.ipynb I am trying to import the claims module:
from app.models.claims.common import Box, Vda

However I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 from datetime import UTC, datetime
----> 3 from app.models.claims.common import Box, Vda

Why is it not able to import?

How do you execute the code?

I just click play on VSCode inside the notebook code block

Correct Import Statements:
Ensure your import statement is correct and matches the directory structure:
from models.claims.common import Box, Vda


app.models.claims.common matches the directory structure, too.

Notebook location
The notebook does not have access to the scripts. There are multiple ways to solve this problem. The quickfix, move the notebook to a location that contains the package as a subfolder, such as root.
A longer solution would be wrapping app as a package and then importing it. That way, you could import it even without the notebook being on a hierarchically superior folder.
[EDIT] Another, better quick fix, would be to use the os package to travel to the location and set it as a working directory without moving the notebook os.chdir(your/path/to/app)

app is already a package

But if the environment does not recognize it, then code in the notebooks folder wouldn't be able to find it. Hard to know beyond this without delving into the environments, what are you using to set app as a package?

There is a __init__.py file inside the app.py folder
